# Rails, REST, which controller displays what?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

I have a controller which manages `Users` and a different one for `Reservations`.
Where should the code be located that displays all reservations for a specific user?
Is this done in the `User` controller or the `Reservation` controller?

Comment: You could have a controller like "UserReservetionsController" which could have all the index/show/edit/delete actions related to the User - Reservations entries.

Comment: Or if the Relation model is defined like Relation belongs_to User (the Relation table has the user_id), you should use nested resources and nested routes. Like this: "/users/:user_id/reservations/:reservation_id see more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: wow - so far I think I have gotten all permutations of possible answers! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. If you're dealing with a nested resource (in other words you want to be able to access something like `/users/4321/reservations`), you should take a look at [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources), which is outdated for Rails 2 but still useful.

What you probably want is to have the code be in the `ReservationsController` under the `index` action, but it depends on what you're planning to do. Nonetheless, something like this would make sense:

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @reservations = Reservations.where(user: params[:user_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: This: `User.find(params[:user_id]).reservations` generates 2 SQL queries. The Reservation model has the user_id in its table, why not querying directly from the Reservation model? `Reservation.where(user_id: params[:user_id])`: this generates only 1 SQL query.

Comment: @MrYoshiji Yes this is true, I was just trying to elucidate the approach I was suggesting. Fixed the answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are slightly off base here... your models should have an association; e.g.:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :reservations
end
```

Your UserController#show might be

```
def show
 @user = User.find(params["id")
end
```

And then the view would have something like:

```
<ul>
    <% @user.reservations.each do |r| %>
    <li><%= r.details =%></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

The association opens it up so that you can call the needed object from either. You could just as easily show `@reservation.user.name` in the Reservation view

Answer (score 0):

> Where should the code be located that displays all reservations for a specific user?

It depends. If you want to show reservations for a specific user on his detail page (/users/42), then UsersController#show action is perfectly reasonable. If you want to make a search form, then it's basically a filter on the ReservationsControler#index action.